# Generating an Asset-folder in pimcore

Tags: directory, assets, pimcore

I can generate an Object-folder in pimcore via `Pimcore\Model\Object\Folder::create()`. Unfortunately there is no such function in `Asset\Folder`.
Has anyone an idea how to generate an Asset-folder without hacking it into the DB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is also possible to use

```
Asset\Service::createFolderByPath("/this/is/a/example/");
```

for generate folders in the asset directory. The advantage is that it generate the folders recursively.

Comment: This function works for DataObjects and Documents as well:
$folder = DataObject\Service::createFolderByPath('/some/long/path');

Answer (score 4):

Take a look how the Admin UI does it in:

[/pimcore/modules/admin/controllers/AssetController.php / addFolderAction()](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/master/pimcore/modules/admin/controllers/AssetController.php#L331)  Line 331:

```
$asset = Asset::create($this->getParam("parentId"), array(
    "filename" => $this->getParam("name"),
    "type" => "folder",
    "userOwner" => $this->user->getId(),
    "userModification" => $this->user->getId()
));
```

Comment: Ah, 'type' is what I was missing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @chluehr How can we add metadata while creating the folder? I do not want to hit DB twice.

Comment: @FaiyazAlam , mehtod Asset::create has 3rd parameter $save. If you will set it to false, the object would be returned without saving, so you can call $asset = Asset::create($parentId, $params, false); $asset->setMetadata($metaData);$asset->save(); This will allow to set metadata in Pimcore Asset before it is created.

Comment: @EugeneKaurov thanks. this is something new I learnt.